# Visual Studio 2017 No detecta DataSet

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque sucede, ya que si ingreso la clase dentro de la una carpeta tipo app_code en el sitio web no hay problema, soy nuevo con c# y mysql lamento si es una tontera, por otro lado, ¿la cadena de conexión está bien?, gracias :)

Pd: es visual studio 2017.

Comment: Agregaste la referencia a System.Data?

Comment: Gracias por responder tan pronto. Pero sí, lo hice.

Comment: En la parte de errores que te dice?

Comment: CS0246  C# El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'DataSet' no se encontró #¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?# 

Pero como dije ya puse "using System.data".

Comment: Perdón, pero si veo el screenshot en la parte de referencias del proyecto Datos. System.Data no está

Comment: ¿Es "System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject" lo que debería aparecer?

Comment: @JuanGonzález Ya actualice mi respuesta si cumple con lo que buscas marcala como la mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como lo veo estas realizando un proyecto del tipo **`Aplicacion Universal`**  en donde `DataTable/ Dataset/ DataViews` ya  no existen dentro del espacio de nombre  `System.Data` por eso no te lo reconoce.

Para seguir usando **MySql** la primera solución seria usar el espacio de nombres `MySql.Data.RT`  que te permitiría hacer la ejecución de querys. [Link de la solución](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/how-to%3a-using-mysql-connectornet-with-windows-store-apps)

La otra solución seria usar el **Connector.NET 6.9** de mysql para la ejecución de tus querys.
[Link de la solución](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074112/Using-MySQL-Database-with-UWP)

Fuente:  [Hilo de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280409/universal-windows-datatable-is-missing) , 
[System.Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185500.aspx)

Comment: Gracias, ¿entonces que podría hacer?.

Comment: ¿El conn.Open() te lo reconoce?

Comment: Agregué una captura de pantalla de lo que aparece :/

Comment: @JuanGonzález Actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Estoy empezando con visual, y es un ejemplo del profesor, ahora bien, y como dije, si lo pongo en una carpeta app_code de la página web funciona, no entiendo la razón, puede que sea esta cuenta con más extensiones para agregar y por ende también las posea , esperaré a volver a clase, pero no deja de resultarme curioso. Sin embargo intentaré ver las opciones que diste.
**Gracias** :)

Comment: @JuanGonzález solo por curiosidad ¿Que tipo de proyecto es tu Web? Si es correcto lo que pienso no es del tipo universal cosa que ya de por si te permitiría usar el MySql normalmente

Comment: Pues he creado un sitio web ASP.NET en blanco y en la carpeta app_code la clase funciona sin problemas, luego las bibliotecas de clases de la solución no reconocen el DataSet, la cosa es que tengo dos profesores uno llama la DB desde el sitio web otro programa en  tres capas y yo quiero programar en tres capas.

Comment: Es justamente eso lo que te digo. Tu proyecto ASP NET no es del tipo universal por eso te permite usar Dataset a diferencia de tu biblioteca que te sugiera que crees una que sea normal.

Comment: Ahh, ya entiendo, lamento quitarte más tiempo del debido. 


Ten buen día y  muchas gracias.

Editado: probado y funcionando.